# Creating instance of nested class

Tags: c++, c++11

I have code like this:

```
class outer{
   int x;
   class inner{
     int y;
   }

   void print(int t_x){
     std::cout << t_x;
   }
}
```

Is there a way to create only instance of class inner? And if this is possible, will this object have acces to outer::print function ?

Comment: How would "inner" have access to anything of "outer" if you never create an instance of "outer"??

Comment: `inner` works exactly like you'd defined it outside `outer`, but its scope is limited to `outer`. (Java's "inner class" concept does not exist in C++.)

Comment: `inner` is private, you can't create an instance of it outside `outer`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to create only instance of class inner?

Yes, you can let have `outer` creating as many instance independent instances (e.g. as static members or local variables in `static` member functions) of `inner` as you want.

> And if this is possible, will this object have acces to `outer::print` function ?

No. `outer::print()` is only available with an instance of `outer`, so at least a parameter or a local instance of `outer` will be needed.

---

The `outer` and `inner` class declarations are completely independent regarding instantiation. It's only about the scope:

- The `inner` type is only seen at the `private` `outer` class scope (can be circumvented using anonymous `auto` types outside of `outer` received through functions)
- `inner` has access to any `public`, `protected` and `private` members of `outer` (special scope priviledges)
- `outer` has access to any `public` members of `inner` as usual (no special priviledges)

Comment: also a `friend` of `outer` could create instances of `inner`. I suspect that it wasnt OPs intention to ask only about a `private` `inner`. In case it is `public` anybody can access `inner`

Comment: What do you mean by "at least a parameter will be needed"

Answer (score 3):

That's called a nested class, not an inner class.
The most frequent use case of nested classes are iterators of standard library. Their templates are declared in related container templates.

To create an instance of nested class, one should  have access to its declaration. It can be instantiated only from `outer` class or from a friend of that class.

```
class outer{
   int x;   

   class inner;
public:
   void doThings();
};

   class outer::inner
   {
   public:    
     void print(class outer *p)
     {
       std::cout << "x=" << p->x;
     }
   };

 void outer::doThings()
 {
    outer::inner a;
    a. print(this);
 }

int main()
{
    outer a;

    a.doThings();
    return 0;
}
```

Methods of `outer::inner` will have access to `private` and `protected` members of `outer`

> **9.7 Nested class declarations [class.nest]**
>
> **1** A class can be declared within another class. A class declared
>   within another is called a nested class. The name of a nested class is
>   local to its enclosing class. The nested class is in the scope of its
>   enclosing class. [ Note: See 5.1 for restrictions on the use of
>   non-static data members and non-static member functions. —end note ]

```
int x;
int y;
struct enclose {
    int x;
    static int s;
    struct inner {
        void f(int i) {
            int a = sizeof(x); // OK: operand of sizeof is an unevaluated operand
            x = i; // error: assign to enclose::x
            s = i; // OK: assign to enclose::s
            ::x = i; // OK: assign to global x
            y = i; // OK: assign to global y
        }
        void g(enclose* p, int i) {
            p->x = i; // OK: assign to enclose::x
        }
    };
};
inner* p = 0; // error: inner not in scope
```

> **2** Member functions and static data members of a nested class can be
>   defined in a namespace scope enclosing the definition of their class.

```
struct enclose {
    struct inner {
        static int x;
        void f(int i);
    };
};
int enclose::inner::x = 1;
void enclose::inner::f(int i) { / ... / }
```

> **3** If class X is defined in a namespace scope, a nested class Y may be declared in class X and later defined in the definition of class X
>   or be later defined in a namespace scope enclosing the definition of
>   class X.

```
class E {
    class I1; // forward declaration of nested class
    class I2;
    class I1 { }; // definition of nested class
};
class E::I2 { }; // definition of nested class
```

> **4** Like a member function, a friend function (11.3) defined within a
>   nested class is in the lexical scope of that class; it obeys the same
>   rules for name binding as a static member function of that class
>   (9.4), but it has no special access rights to members of an enclosing
>   class.

Comment: Are you sure about your last sentence? That's unexpected for me.

Comment: Looks like you're right: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f20d49cb10b87a4 I'll correct my answer about that.

Comment: @user0042 See 9.7  of  standard. well, you see the code, where `outer::inner::print` accesses private  member variable.