# Syntax for creating instance of templated nested class?

Tags: c++, class, templates

Quick question: how can I initialize this? The syntax isn't working.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 
template<typename TYPE> 
class Heap1  {
    class Node {
        public:
            friend Heap1;

        private:
            TYPE elt;
            Node *child;
    }; // Node 
};

int main() {
    Heap1<int>.Node var;

    return 0; }
```

I'm reading this answer but the syntax isn't too clear to me: [Creating instance of nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650554/creating-instance-of-nested-class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> Heap1<int>.Node var;
> ```
>
> The syntax isn't working

Try

```
Heap1<int>::Node var;
```

But actually, you can't. `Heap1<>::Node` is `private` and thus inaccessible from the outside world.